# Changing registered DbContext in DI for different web projects but maintaining generic libraries that consume it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I've come across this [Magic super DRY code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/june/patterns-and-practices-super-dry-development-for-asp-net-core) and decided to make a simple one myself. I basically plan to create generic libraries where when I apply it in a new project, I'll just inject the project specific DbContext and have a simple CRUD endpoints with fewer codes needed.

With that said, I've created the generic libraries and was able to successfully test it. Now that I'm trying to use it in a new project, I can't find a way to inject my project specific DbContext to the libraries.

Here's what I've got so far:

**The generic library:**

**DbContext**

```
public class ApiContext : DbContext
{
    //Sample DbSet during my testing in same solution
    public DbSet<RootAccount> RootAccounts { get; set; }

    public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options) : base(options){}
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RootAccount>().ApplyBaseModelSchema();
        modelBuilder.Entity<RootAccount>().Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

**GenericRepository**

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseModel 
{
    public ApiContext Context { get; }
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public GenericRepository(ApiContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        Context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetByIDAsync(object id)
    {
        return await DbSet.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        //Added another layer of repository mainly for purposes such as this
        entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
    //more methods here
}
```

**Unit Of Work**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    private ApiContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(ApiContext webApiContext)
    {
        _context = webApiContext;
    }

    public GenericRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseModel
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as GenericRepository<TEntity>;

        var repository = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(_context);
        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);

        return repository;
    }

    public ApiContext Context { get => _context; }

    public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"E:\errors.txt", e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**CrudService**

```
public class CrudService<T> : ICrudService<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private IDataMapper _mapper;
    public CrudService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IDataMapper mapper)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<DTO> GetAsync<DTO>(int id) where DTO : BaseDtoModel, new()
    {
        var model = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<T>().GetByIDAsync(id);
        var dto = _mapper.Map<DTO>(model);
        return dto;
    }
    public async Task<int> AddAsync<DTO>(DTO dtoModel) where DTO : BaseDtoModel, new()
    {
        var model = _mapper.Map<T>(dtoModel);
        _unitOfWork.GetRepository<T>().Insert(model);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
        return model.Id;
    }
    //more methods here
}
```

**Startup**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //this works because the UoW and GenericRepository hardcodes ApiContext and the same type is registered here.
        services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnString")));

        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IDataMapper, DataMapper>();
        services.AddTransient(typeof(ICrudService<>), typeof(CrudService<>));
    }
```

**The Problem**

If I use this library to a new project, let's say an Accounting system, I want to register an `AccountingDbContext` in Startup instead of `ApiContext` obviously. I've tried to refactor my UoW and GenericRepository to use the base class `DbContext` instead but doesn't seem to work either. My gut feeling tells me to create a `IDbContext` but I'm at loss on how to implement it.

Sorry for the wall of code but I believe they'll explain my issue better than I could in my write up.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after struggling for a couple of hours on this, I've found a solution minutes after I post this question.

It clicked on me that I could still refactor my `UoW` and `GenericRepository` to use the generic `DbContext`. Then on startup, I could just provide a different implementation for `DbContext` like this:

```
     services.AddDbContext<DbContext, ApiContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnString")));
```

I didn't know we could do this and that we can only provide an implementation when registering interfaces (Hence my idea of `IDbContext`). Testing it right now and everything seems fine so far.